# Issue in setting --sysctl net.core parameter with docker container

Tags: docker, oracle-rac

i am facing a critical issue while running oracle rac database in docker container solely as net.core* parameters are not set in the container. I also tried with --net=host but that does not seem to help as it uses host network which limit connectivity between two rac containers and also hinders the installation.

Is there any workaround for setting --sysctl net.core* parameters with docker run?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid that sysctl requires --privileged flag passed to docker run

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response @odk but i had tried using --priviledged flag, yet it showed this error "/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default: no such file or directory" as this file is not present inside the container.